# Query to retrieve portion of a date

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I have date values that are stored in the following format:
Thursday, December 19, 2019 12:00 AM

I need to retrieve just the month and day however I have been unsuccesful as I keep getting the time as well. Is there query that will just get the date 12/19 or December 19 as a date because I need to compare it against today's date without the year.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're doing this on something *other than* Marketing Cloud...

What you have here isn't a date, it's a *datetime*. While there are [SOQL Date functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm) that can help, their primary use is in filters (i.e. the `WHERE` clause) and you can't compare the result of a Date function with a Date literal like `TODAY` or `THIS_YEAR`. In general, you can't change the type of a field that you get back in the result of a query.

In Apex, the Datetime class does have methods that can extract the Date portion (e.g. `date()`, see [the Datetime documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm) for more information) as well as methods to extract the month and day.

While you can use Apex to further refine the results of a query, what you're looking to sounds like it's simple enough that you could use the 'ol formula field workaround. That is, you can't create the filter directly in a query, but you can create a formula field that does. You'd then use that formula field in your query.

Something like

```
AND(
    MONTH(My_Datetime_Field__c) = MONTH(TODAY()),
    DAY(My_Datetime_Field__c) = DAY(TODAY())
)
```

Your formula should return a boolean value. Assuming it's named `Month_And_Day_Matches__c`, your query would end up looking like

```
[SELECT Id FROM MyObject__c WHERE Month_And_Day_Matches__c = true]
```

Comment: But the formula approach is a Bad Idea, as it causes a Full Table Scan, so use with cation.

Comment: I like the formula idea, however I am doing this in Marketing Cloud automation. I do have the option of getting the datetime from the source DE and breaking it up and putting it into a temporary DE. Are there more options if I do something like that? Thanks.

Comment: @gh0st Then you should edit your question to remove the apex and soql tags, and add the marketing-cloud tag. Marketing cloud is an entirely different beast, and I have no experience with it.